# Backnet binding in openhab and how to configure the .cfg file

Tags: openhab, bacnet

I downloaded from github a [backnet addon](https://github.com/arrizer/BACNet-openHAB-binding) and put it in the addon folder. But I don't know how to configure the .cfg fileand readme file could not help. Has anyone ever used this addon?? I want it so I could read the data from a [schneider electric server](https://documentation.smartstruxurelite.com/display/DR/MPM+BACnet+Integration) . Because it is not an official addon you think that it would be easy or should I find another way and if you know anyone??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I finally made it to read values.
As it comes to the .cfg file you only have to give the ip(bacnet has no security) that means something like this.

```
 ############################### Bacnet Binding#######################################
#
# Refresh interval in milliseconds (optional, defaults to 60000ms)
bacnet:refresh=60000

# Set the bacnet network address
bacnet:hostname=<your ip>
```

But also you have to  put the new bacnet items in the .items file. The readme file that is on the github is wrong

example item
`Switch reflectors_west_2 "Reflectors West Center" <reflector> (Reflector) {bacnet="701105:5:3"}`

```
-deviceID-->701105
-objectType-->5
-objectID-->3
```

- `deviceID` is the instance ID (integer) of the device as configured on your local network (it is *not* the IP address of the device)
- `objectType` is one of the following:
- analogInput = 0
- analogOutput = 1
- analogValue = 2
- binaryInput = 3
- binaryOutput = 4
- binaryValue = 5
- `objectID`is the instance ID (integer) of the object you want to tie to this openHAB item

I found  how to configure the .items [here](https://knx-user-forum.de/forum/supportforen/openhab/38994-%E2%88%9A-openhab-und-bacnet)